# RS in awk language

Tags: bash, awk, mawk

I'm learning awk programming language and i'm stuck to a problem here.

I've a file(awk.dat), having the following content:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Maecenas pellentesque erat vel tortor consectetur condimentum.
Nunc enim orci, euismod id nisi eget, interdum cursus ex.
Curabitur a dapibus tellus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Aliquam interdum mauris volutpat nisl placerat, et facilisis.
```

I'm using below command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="*, *";ORS="<<<---\n"} {print $0}' awk.dat
```

it's returning me the error:

```
awk: run time error: regular expression compile failed (missing operand)
*, *
    FILENAME="" FNR=0 NR=0
```

While, if i use the command: `awk 'BEGIN{RS=" *, *";ORS="<<<---\n"} {print $0}' awk.dat`, it's giving me the required result.

I need to understand this part: `RS=" *, *"`, the meaning of the space between double-quotes and `*` before `,`, due to which it's throwing the error.

Expected Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<<<---
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Maecenas pellentesque erat vel tortor consectetur condimentum.
Nunc enim orci<<<---
euismod id nisi eget<<<---
interdum cursus ex.
Curabitur a dapibus tellus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<<<---
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Aliquam interdum mauris volutpat nisl placerat<<<---
et facilisis.
<<<---
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you intend to mean by `*, *` ? `awk` parses it as a regex, in which language `*` is a quantifier that specifies how many times the previous token should be matched. In your first try there is no such previous token for the first `*`, while in the second it's a space character which makes the regex valid. The second variation is probably what you're looking for if you want to use a comma surrounded by any amount of spaces as RS.

Comment: What version of awk are you using? I believe it is mawk. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Yup, it's `mawk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"[space1]*,[space2]*"
```

is a regex, it matches string with:

zero or many spaces (space1) followed by a comma, then followed by zero or many spaces (space2)

The first one `"*,[space]*"` was wrong, because `*` has special meaning in regex. It means that repeating the matched group/character zero or many times. You cannot put it at very beginning.

Comment: Thanks Kent, revisited the basic concepts :-)

Comment: and just be aware the a multi-char regexp for RS is gawk-specific. Other awks will truncate that at the first character.

Comment: @EdMorton mawk will treat it also special as an ERE unless its a single character.

Comment: depends on the mawk version - mawk is always playing catch-up to gawk for some features.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that, according to POSIX, `RS` is defined as a single character and **not** a regular expression.

> The first character of the string value of `RS` shall be the input record separator; a <newline> by default. If `RS` contains more than one character, the results are unspecified. If `RS` is null, then records are separated by sequences consisting of a <newline> plus one or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and a <newline> shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of `FS` is.
>
> **<sub>source: [Awk Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

This implies that `RS=" *, *"` leads to *undefined behaviour*.

Other versions of awk, who implement extensions to POSIX, might have a different approach to what `RS` stands for. Examples are GNU awk and mawk. Both implement `RS` to be a regular expression, but both implementations are slightly different. The summary wrt to the usage of <asterisk> is:

```
| RS   | awk (posix)  | gawk             | mawk             |
|------+--------------+------------------+------------------|
| "*"  | "<asterisk>" | "<asterisk>"     | "<asterisk>"     |
| "*c" | undefined    | "<asterisk>c"    | undefined        |
| "c*" | undefined    | "","c","ccc",... | "","c","ccc",... |

c is any character
```

The above should explain the error of the OP as `RS="*, *"` is an invalid regular expression according to mawk.

```
$ echo "abc" | ./mawk '/*c/'
mawk: line 1: regular expression compile failed (missing operand)
```

**GNU awk:** The manual of GNU awk states the following:

> When using `gawk`, **the value of `RS` is not limited to a one-character string. It can be any regular expression** (see [Regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp)). (c.e.) In general, each record ends at the next string that matches the regular expression; the next record starts at the end of the matching string.
>
> **<sub>source: [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#gawk-split-records)</sub>**

To understand the usage of <asterisk> in the regular expression in GNU awk, we find:

> **<asterisk> `*`** This symbol means that the preceding regular expression should be repeated as many times as necessary to find a match. For example, `ph*` applies the `*` symbol to the preceding `h` and looks for matches of one `p` followed by any number of `h`s. This also matches just `p` if no `h`s are present.
>
> There are two subtle points to understand how `*` works. First, the `*` applies only to the single preceding regular expression component (e.g., in `ph*`, it applies just to the `h`). To cause `*` to apply to a larger subexpression, use parentheses: `(ph)*` matches `ph`, `phph`, `phphph`, and so on.
>
> Second, `*` finds as many repetitions as possible. If the text to be matched is `phhhhhhhhhhhhhhooey`, `ph*` matches all of the `h`s.
>
> **<sub>source: [GNU Regular expression operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Operators)</sub>**

It must be mentioned, however that:

> In <s>POSIX awk</s> and gawk, **the `*`, `+` and `?` operators stand for themselves when there is nothing in the regexp that precedes them.** For example, `/+/` matches a literal plus sign. However, many other versions of awk treat such a usage as a syntax error.
>
> **<sub>source: [GNU Regular expression operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Operators)</sub>**

Thus, setting `RS="*, *"`, implies that it would match the strings `"*,"`, `"*, "`, `"*,  "`, ...

```
$ echo "a,b, c" | awk 'BEGIN{RS="*, *"}1'
a,b, c
$ echo "a*,b, c" | awk 'BEGIN{RS="*, *"}1'
a
b, c
```

**mawk:** The manual of GNU awk states the following:

> **12. Multi-line records**
>   Since `mawk` interprets **`RS` as a regular expression**, multi-line records are easy.
>
> **<sub>source: [`man mawk`](https://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.html)</sub>**

but

> **11. Splitting strings, records and files**
> Awk programs use the same algorithm to split strings into  arrays  with
>          `split()`, and records into fields on `FS`.  **mawk uses essentially the same algorithm to split files into records on `RS`.**
>
> `Split(expr,A,sep)` works as follows:
>
> 1. <snip>
> 2. If `sep = " "` (a single space), then <SPACE> is trimmed from the front  and back of `expr`, and `sep` becomes <SPACE>.  mawk defines <SPACE> as the regular expression `/[ \t\n]+/`.  Otherwise `sep` is treated  as  a  regular expression, **except that meta-characters
>      are ignored for a string of length 1**, e.g.,  `split(x,  A,  "*")` and `split(x, A, /\*/)` are the same.
> 3. <snip>
>
> **<sub>source: [`man mawk`](https://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.html)</sub>**

The manual makes **no** mention of how a regular expression starting with a meta-character should be interpreted (eg. "*c")

---

**Note:** in the GNU awk section I struck through POSIX awk, as, according to POSIX, a regular expression of the form `"*, "` leads to undefined behaviour. (This is independent of defining `RS` as `RS` is anyway not an ERE in POSIX awk)

> The awk utility shall make use of the extended regular expression notation (see XBD [Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04))
>
> **<sub>source: [Awk Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

and

> **`*+?{`**
>   The <asterisk>, <plus-sign>, <question-mark>, and <left-brace> shall be special except when used in a bracket expression (see RE Bracket Expression). **Any of the following uses produce undefined results:**
>
> - **If these characters appear first in an ERE**, or immediately following an unescaped <vertical-line>, <circumflex>, <dollar-sign>, or <left-parenthesis>
> - If a <left-brace> is not part of a valid interval expression (see EREs Matching Multiple Characters)
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04)</sub>**

Comment: Thanks kvantour for the explanation, i've one query, it may sound stupid : In my input file, there's no `space` anywhere before a `,` . So, how does the `*` in `RS=" *, *"` matches occurrence of zero or more spaces?

Comment: @A.K, how about posting expected output sample too in your post in code tags, may be you could get more thoughts too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : I've updated with expected output.

Comment: @A.K In regular expressions, the <asterisk> `*` is a metacharacter for zero or more instances of the preceding character. So the expression `" *,"` matches zero or more spaces before a comma.

Comment: @A.K I have updated the answer to be more accurate wrt to the differences between gnu and mawk (as I expect you are using mawk)

Comment: @kvantour: Thanks for your precious time and the beautiful explanation. It's clearer to me now:)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following once.

```
awk '{gsub(", ","<<<---" ORS)} 1;END{print "<<<---"}'   Input_file
```

Comment: @A.K, could you please this solution once too https://stackoverflow.com/a/53618562/5866580 and let me know then?

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13,this works perfectly!!! but i've still the same query stuck in my head. In my input file, how does the `<asterisk>` in `RS=" *, *"` matches occurrence of zero or more spaces?